# Continuously extend of bounded tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, ricci-flow

If $g(t)$ is Ricci flow on $[0,T)$, and
$$
|Rm|\le M ~~~~~~ \forall t\in[0,T),
$$
By the Metric equivalence
$$
e^{-2Mt} g(0) \le g(t)\le e^{2Mt} g(0),
$$
I know $g(t)$ is bounded (namely, there is $A,B\ge0$ such that $A|\epsilon|^2\le g(\epsilon, \epsilon)\le B|\epsilon|^2$). Topping state that $g(t)$ can be extended continuously to $[0,T]$. But in my view, bounded function may not be extended continuously, for example
$$
f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x} 
$$
is bounded on (0,1], but it can't be extended continuously to $[0,1]$. Of course, I don't know the case of tensor.

Since my English is poor, I add some picture of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow against that I misunderstand it.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $g(t)$ satisfies the RF equation, hence is uniformly Lipschitz as a function of $t$. Topping is assuming that his reader does not need such hints. But it's good that you are checking every small detail!